# Error creating dockerfile with apt

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am trying to create a small Dockerfile based on Ubuntu or Debian.
This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN "apt update"
```

When I try to build the command, I get this error:

```
 l@Notebook-Lab:~/progetti/dns_analyzer$ docker build -t my_dns .
 Sending build context to Docker daemon  15.36kB
 Step 1/2 : FROM debian:latest
 ---> 8d31923452f8
 Step 2/2 : RUN "apt update"
 ---> Running in 3a0ee422e849  
 /bin/sh: 1: apt update: not found
 The command '/bin/sh -c "apt update"' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

When I launch the command "apt update" from a bash terminal inside the container everything works fine.

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) you probably need to get rid of the quotes or use the other format.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the quotes (you are trying to run the command `apt update` rather than the command `apt` with argument `update`), switch to `apt-get` (apt does not have a stable interfaces for scripting), and you should also be chaining any `apt-get update` command with your `apt-get install` command to remove the risk of a stale cache:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y --no-install-recommends \
      git \
      vim
```

See the best practices doc for more details: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/#run